# React Native fast scroll list view

Tags: react-native

In react-native how to implement fast scroll list view like android have as the below image.

[image]

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-alphabetlistview
It seems a little bit different but you can create a custom view for the header.

Answer (score 0):

As per given in the comment you can use https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-alphabetlistview. But it is not exactly same that you are looking at. The library will only give you alphabetically sectioned list. But other things that you need to take care.

I have not tried it but only can give you hint. Check out the documentation. There is callback method available : **onScrollToSection** . This method will return section when you scroll down the list according to [this](https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-alphabetlistview/blob/master/components/SelectableSectionsListView.js) . Make use of it to create your alphabet bubble on right.